# Can I separate a string using a a number as the starting point and a comma as the ending point?

Tags: javascript, string, split, slice

So here's an example string:
CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Management Support Services,OU=Divisions,OU=Accounts,DC=company,DC=com

I only need to get the first name out of this string. In this case the name being John Doe. I can't hard code a number of characters in as the names there can vary in length.

Basically I need to select the string after CN= and then end it at the first comma.

The first number can always be 3 characters since the CN= is always there. Is there anyway for me to use the first comma as the end point?

I'm trying to do something like this.

let name = reports[i].mgrdn;
let result = name.split(3, ",")

Any help would be appreciated. Even just a suggestion about what method to use.

Comment: You've tagged `split` so why aren't you using that?

Comment: I was experimenting with a couple different options and seeing what would work. I just happened to have slice in the piece I copy pasted. Edited the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you need.

```
 result = name.split(',')[0].split('=')[1];
```

Of course you should probably validate the format is what is expected too.

As @freedomn-m says...

Step-by-step:

- take name, split on comma, take first entry (all text before first comma),
- split that on = and take all text after the equal (from the text before the first comma)

Comment: That worked perfectly! How exactly is that working though?

Comment: Step-by-step: take name, split on comma, take first entry (all text before first comma), split *that* on `=` and take all text after the equal (from the text before the first comma)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the indexOf method and then slice

```js
function extractFirstName(str) {
  let startIndex = str.indexOf("CN=") + 3;
  let endIndex = str.indexOf(",", startIndex);
  if (startIndex < 0 || endIndex < 0) {
    return null;
  }
  let firstName = str.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
  return firstName;
}

// Example
let name = "CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Management Support Services,OU=Divisions,OU=Accounts,DC=company,DC=com";
let firstName = extractFirstName(name);
console.log(firstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex:

```js
let regex = new RegExp("\=(.*?)\,");
let input = "CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Management Support Services,OU=Divisions,OU=Accounts,DC=company,DC=com"

let [_, name] = input.match(regex)

console.log("Name:", name);
```

https://regex101.com/r/i4p0Ks/1

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get more than just the first you can convert it in to query params.

```js
const str = 'CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Management Support Services,OU=Divisions,OU=Accounts,DC=company,DC=com';
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(str.replace(/,/g,"&"));
console.log('CN', searchParams.get("CN"));
console.log('OU', searchParams.getAll("OU"));
console.log('DC', searchParams.getAll("DC"));
```